# Javascript array has more elements than the length value

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working with FabricJS, when you add a few things to a FabricJS canvas it tracks them with an internal variable *canvas["_objects"]*

However when I *console.log()* this I get what you see in firebug [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECq86.png)

[image]

Looking at this array you would assume there are only 7 elements in it, when you use firebug to expand it there are 9, the length is 9. But when I do *console.log(canvas["_objects"].length)* I only get 7 returned.

I can expand the last 2 elements and see them. But when I try to access them directly (by hard coding the value 9 into the loop that iterates this array, rather than relying on the length property) I get an error, as if the last two elements dont exist.

But if they dont exist how can firebug see them? And they have been added to the canvas.

I dont even know where to begin with this, never seen anything like it.

Comment: please add an [mcve]

Comment: Those elements maybe got added later after you accessed your array. In the `console` itself, you'll see the icon `i` which says _"the value was evaluated just now"_ meaning initially when you logged the array there were 7 elements, but 2 new elements got added later and console.log prints the current value

Comment: Thanks abhishekkannojia I'll try and test this. 

Sagar V I'll see if I can recreate this in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

abhishekkannojia was correct, the elements were added after the fact. Soemone elses merge had caused this, which is why I couldn't see it.

Thanks abhishekkannojia